# How to get video dimensions using FFMPEG

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

My goal is to pass a Video file to FFMPEG and to get its dimension as output.How can I achieve this. Can anyone help me out with sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void GetVideoInfo(string input)
    {
        //  set up the parameters for video info.
        string @params = string.Format("-i {0}", input);
        string output = Run(ffmpegProcess, @params);

        //get the video format
        re = new Regex("(\\d{2,3})x(\\d{2,3})");
        Match m = re.Match(output);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            int width = 0; int height = 0;
            int.TryParse(m.Groups[1].Value, out width);
            int.TryParse(m.Groups[2].Value, out height);
        }
    }

private static string Run(string process/*ffmpegFile*/, string parameters)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(process))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot find {0}.", process));

        //  Create a process info.
        ProcessStartInfo oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(process, parameters);
        //oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //oInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //oInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //oInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        //  Create the output and streamreader to get the output.
        string output = null;
        //StreamReader outputStream = null;

        //  Try the process.
        //try
        //{
        //  Run the process.
        Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(oInfo);

        proc.WaitForExit();

        //outputStream = proc.StandardError;
        //output = outputStream.ReadToEnd();    

        proc.Close();
        //}
        //catch( Exception ex )
        //{
        //    output = ex.Message;
        //}
        //finally
        //{
        //    //  Close out the streamreader.
        //    if( outputStream != null )
        //        outputStream.Close();
        //}
        return output;
    }
```

You should uncomment some code to get this working. Hope it helps.

I have code that gets more info from the video, different converts, etc. The code above is sliced and may need slight modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [FFMPEG-C# Library](http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

You should make C# process that execute ffprobe with command "-i {0}" ({0} is video path).

I dont know why but ffmpeg always return output in Errors channel when you run it on c# process, therefore you must read StandardError Stream after process finished.

When we got the output string we can find out resolution with running a Regex on it.

```
int intVideoWidth = 0; int intVideoHeight = 0;

Process processGetOriginalVideoData = new Process();
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe";
processGetOriginalVideoData.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-i {0}", strMyVideoPath);
processGetOriginalVideoData.Start();
processGetOriginalVideoData.WaitForExit();

StreamReader processGetOriginalVideoDataOutputStream = processGetOriginalVideoData.StandardError;
string strProcessGetOriginalVideoDataOutput = await processGetOriginalVideoDataOutputStream.ReadToEndAsync();

processGetOriginalVideoData.Kill();

var resolutionRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\\d{2,4})x(\\d{2,4})");
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match resolutionRegexMatches = resolutionRegex.Match(strProcessGetOriginalVideoDataOutput);
if (resolutionRegexMatches.Success)
{
    int.TryParse(resolutionRegexMatches.Groups[1].Value, out intVideoWidth);
    int.TryParse(resolutionRegexMatches.Groups[2].Value, out intVideoHeight);
}
```

Comment: No need for a regex. [ffprobe can output the resolution directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29585066/).