# how to check if video is landscape or portrait using ffmpeg php?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I have to check the video is landscape or portrait before rotate using ffmpge .
please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using ffmpeg we cant check the video is taken landscape mode or portrite mode in iphone.

we need to install mediainfo or exiftool

if we install exiftool use the below commands

exec('exiftool  path/to/filename/ | grep Rotation');

from this we can get the rotation of  the videos

if rotation is 90° the videos taken in portraite mode in iphone

if rotation is 0° the videos taken in landscape mode in iphone

Comment: This works exactly like:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream_tags=rotate -of csv=p=0 myfile.mp4

Comment: this returns an empty line when I run it

Answer (score 3):

[Getting video dimension from ffmpeg -i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362130/getting-video-dimension-from-ffmpeg-i)

1. Get info.
2. Extract dimensions.
3. If x < y, then portrait. Else landscape.

eg:

```
$output = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $myvideo");
$out_arr = explode("\n", $output);
foreach($out_arr as $line) {
  if( preg_match('/^Stream.*Video:/', trim($line)) ) {
    // match line: Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 597 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc
    $line_arr = explode(',', $line);
    // get field: 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9]
    $target_arr = explode(' ', $line_arr[2]);
    // get parts: 640x360
    $dims = explode('x', $target_arr[0]);
    $res_x = $dims[0];
    $res_y = $dims[1];
  }
}

if( !( isset($res_x) && isset($res_y) ) ) {
  die('Could not get dimensions');
} else {
  $orientation = ($res_x < $res_y) ? 'Portrait' : 'Landscape';
  printf('Resolution: %s x %s\nOrientation: %s\n', $res_x, $res_y, $oreintation);
```

I don't know why you'd want to rotate the video from how it was shot, though. You're going to end up with sideways videos after rotating more likely than not.

Comment: @thanigai if your app is not making use of the sensors in the phone to determine the orientation when the video is shot, then it will *always* be coming in in whatever default orientation iPhone uses. In this case videos will always need to be rotated by a human.

Comment: in iphone its fine. we take and uploaded a video in portrait mode thorugh iphone but when we see through website(not iphone) it plays sideways –

Comment: it is possible to identify the videos either portrait or landscape because the portrait video only i have to rotate.

Comment: because the portrait videos plays sideways

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we are getting 2 types of output "640x268 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67]" and "640x268"

```
$output = shell_exec("FFmpeg -i ".$localVideoPath." -vstats 2>&1");
            $out_arr = explode("\n", $output);
            foreach($out_arr as $line) {
                if( preg_match('/^Stream.*Video:/', trim($line)) ) {
                    $line_arr = explode(',', $line);

                    if (str_contains($line_arr[2], 'x')) {
                        //540x960
                        $target_arr = explode(' ', $line_arr[2]);
                        $dims = explode('x', $target_arr[1]);
                    }else{
                        //640x268 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67]
                        $target_arr = explode(' ', $line_arr[3]);
                        $dims = explode('x', $target_arr[1]);
                    }
                    $res_x = $dims[0];
                    $res_y = $dims[1];
                }
            }

            if(!(isset($res_x) && isset($res_y))){
                //die('Could not get dimensions');
            } else {
                $orientation = ($res_x < $res_y) ? 'Portrait' : 'Landscape';
            }
```