# Using if statement in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

is it possible using if/else statement in ffmpeg ?

I would want to tell ffmpeg if dimension of any video lower than 480p do not touch the height or width otherwise do encode and resize it to 480p, here's my command but it always scale up the video if the video lower than 480p

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 31 -me_method umh -bf 0 -vf scale=480:-2 out.mp4
```

Note that i dont want to use any programming language because it's on windows cmd.

Comment: Use ffprobe to determine the video dimensions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362130/getting-video-dimension-from-ffmpeg-i

Comment: I'm running ffmpeg code in windows cmd alone, im not using any other programming language (i updated my question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notation 480p refers to the height, so I assume that's what you mean.

Use

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 31 -me_method umh -bf 0 -vf scale='if(gte(ih\,480)\,480\,iw)':-2 out.mp4`

This will rescale videos whose height is 480 or more.

Comment: thanks do you test it by your self? because it causes error in my side :

[Parsed_scale_0 @ 000001deab116e80] Invalid size 'if(gte(ih'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001deab4eac00] Error initializing filter 'scale' with args 'if(gte(ih:flags=bicubic'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!

Comment: Your shell needs escaping. Modified.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to check if height is greater than 480p.

If it is, resize the height to 480 and width proportionally.

if it not, do not use the scale filter.

```
-vf scale=-2:'if(gte(ih\,480)\,480\,0)'
```

it says:

use width proportional to height (-2 part)

if input_height is greater than 480, use 480, otherwise use nothing so there is no scaling.

\ is to comment out (ignore) the comma sign (,)

There is also example on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling, to avoid upscaling:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf "scale='min(320,iw)':'min(240,ih)'" input_not_upscaled.png
```

which could be used as this:

```
-vf "scale=-2:'min(480,ih)'"
```