# Showing in-video visual progress bar with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

As OBS Studio lacks a visual indicator to show how far a video has progressed (and when you need to advance to the next scene), I was wondering if there is a command-line option (or solution) to get FFMPEG to re-encode the video and show a progress bar at the bottom of the video that shows how long the video has been playing so far.

Is there such a feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple 3 second example using an animated [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

[image: progress bar example]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "color=c=red:s=1280x10[bar];[0][bar]overlay=-w+(w/10)*t:H-h:shortest=1" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

What you will have to change:

- In the color filter I used `1280` as an example to match the width of `input.mp4`. You can use [`ffprobe` to get the width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29585066/) or the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter to resize to match `input.mp4`.
- In the overlay filter I used `10` as an example for the total duration in seconds of `input.mp4`. You can use [`ffprobe` to get the duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/).

Comment: Is it possible with ffmpeg to do this around the video like it is popilr now on fb or ig? So instead line on the bottom progress would be arond whole video from right to left in the beginning.

Comment: @DejanMilosevic Do you have a link to a video that does what you want?

Comment: I will try to find but it is actually same as this but red line goes all around video.

Comment: Is it possible to add a background to this filter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71245886/adding-a-background-to-an-in-video-visual-progress-bar-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks! I use this method to show the progress when encoding a video, including ffprobe to get width, height and duration and include these values in the ffmpeg command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72004427/3868690

Comment: Can you tell me what "H-h" means? I don't find documentation of it...