# Adding a background to an in-video visual progress bar with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

Using the answer to [Showing in-video visual progress bar with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989964/showing-in-video-visual-progress-bar-with-ffmpeg)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASjyL.gif]

I'm trying to give the progress bar itself a background, so for e.g. the bar will be white and the red progress bar over time will cover it.

My first decision was to apply a drawbox filter, so for my purposes the video is 1280 pixels wide and the duration is 6.027 seconds. I've tried

`ffmpeg -i uuid_nordvpn.mp4 -vf "color=c=red:s=1280x30[bar];[0][bar]overlay=-w+(w/6.072733)*t:H-h:shortest=1, drawbox=x=0:y=720-30:width=1280:height=30:thickness=fill:color=white" out.mp4`

But I got just the white drawbox filter that was drawn on top of the color filter. [image]

The obvious solution was to swap the color and drawbox filter, but that returns an error `Too many inputs specified for the "color" filter`, which I guess means you can only use the color filter at the beginning.

I've also tried applying 2 color filters, the other color filter instead of filling up was going down, but you can't apply 2 color filters, again giving the reason `Too many inputs specified for the "color" filter.`

I'm completely lost at this point, how would I give a background to this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple `color` filters. But `color` filter is a source filter, so it cannot appear in the middle of your filter chain (which is what the error message is saying). It must be the first filter of a chain. This should work for you:

edit: your approach to slide with `overlay` is faster than my original `scale` approaches. I've added all 4 implementations with observed speed:

**1. 2x`color`+2x`overlay`: x14.1**

```
ffmpeg -i uuid_nordvpn.mp4 \
  -vf 'color=c=white:s=1280x30[L0]; \
       color=c=red:s=1280x30[L1]; \
       [L0][L1]overlay=(t/6.072733-1)*w:0:eval=frame[L2]; \
       [in][L2]overlay=0:690:shortest=1[out]' \
  out.mp4
```

**2. `drawbox` + `color` + `overlay`: 13.4x**

```
ffmpeg -i uuid_nordvpn.mp4 \
  -vf '[in]drawbox=0:690:1280:30:white:fill[L0]; \
       color=c=red:s=1280x30[L1]; \
       [L0][L1]overlay=(t/6.072733-1)*w:690:eval=frame:shortest=1[out]' \
  out.mp4
```

**3. 2x`color`+`scale`+2x`overlay`: 5.09x**

```
ffmpeg -i uuid_nordvpn.mp4 \
  -vf 'color=c=white:s=1280x30[L0]; \
       color=c=red:s=1280x30,scale=max(t/6.072733*in_w\,1):in_h:eval=frame[L1]; \
       [L0][L1]overlay=0:0[L2]; \
       [in][L2]overlay=0:690:shortest=1[out]' \
  out.mp4
```

**4. `drawbox` + `color` + `scale` + `overlay`: 5.03x**

```
ffmpeg -i uuid_nordvpn.mp4 \
  -vf '[in]drawbox=0:690:1280:30:white:fill[L0]; \
       color=c=red:s=1280x30,scale=max(t/6.072733*in_w\,1):in_h:eval=frame[L1]; \
       [L0][L1]overlay=0:690:shortest=1[out]' \
  out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

@kesh's answer is great. Here's another alternative if you don't want to overwrite any video data (pad an extra 30px to the bottom instead):

```
ffmpeg -i uuid_nordvpn.mp4 \
  -vf '[in]pad=in_w:in_h+30:0:0:white[pad]; \
       color=c=red:s=1280x30[bar]; \
       [pad][bar]overlay=-w+(w/6.072733)*t:H-h:shortest=1' \
out.mp4
```