# How can I get VideoPlayer source dimensions (width/height)?

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity's new (as of ~5.6.x) Video Player component to programmatically load a video file and play it. But I'd like to be able to detect the dimensions of the source video so that I can resize the render texture target as well as a GameObject containing a control bar for the video.

Is there any way to access these properties?

Currently, I can see it's possible to get the number of frames, etc, which makes me thing I should be able to get the video's dimensions as well, but nothing I can see seems to work.

Comment: maybe you can use ffmpeg library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758042/how-to-get-video-dimensions-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the video dimension such as the width and height from the [`VideoPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html). This can be done by retrieving the [`VideoClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoClip.html) from the [`VideoPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html). Those values can then be accessed from the [`VideoClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoClip.html).

Get VideoPlayer

```
VideoPlayer vplayer = GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
```

Get VideoPlayer clip from the VideoPlayer

```
VideoClip clip = vplayer.clip;
```

Get VideoPlayer dimension width/height

```
float videoWidth = clip.width;
float videoHeight = clip.height;
```

Other important variables you may be interested in:

```
double videoLength = clip.length;
float frameCount = clip.frameCount;
double frameRate = clip.frameRate;
```

If you need help playing video, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144054/using-new-unity-videoplayer-and-videoclip-api-to-play-video) post.

Comment: My apologies; I typed my question at the end of the day and is woefully unclear. I've used that method before with no problem, but as I am downloading the video at runtime I have to use a URL as its source rather than a clip object. As such, "vplayer.clip" per your notation would be null.

Your answer is correct per my original question. You're clearly an SO vet so I'll put this to you: Should I mark your question as correct and create a new question that's more clear; or should I edit my question, rendering your answer inaccurate given the updated data?

Comment: I really like this answer and think it should dedicated to the offline video playing since it will be useful to many people. You can create a new answer dedicated to url video playing and I will answer it. I plan to be away within 30 minutes and will return in hours. If you can put the question within 30 minutes I will attempt to answer it.